# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined, map not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, wordpress

I have read other similar questions here, but I am not a developer, so I need an answer for beginners (or real dummies) to try and fix my little website.

I am getting this error, which makes my directory site not load the listings on the map (thus rendering the site unfunctional):

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:669 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:669)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:668)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Object.apply_meta_filter (map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:660)
    at Object.filter (map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:556)
    at Object.success (map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:195)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at x (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4)
(anonymous) @ map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:669
each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2
(anonymous) @ map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:668
each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2
apply_meta_filter @ map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:660
filter @ map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:556
(anonymous) @ map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:195
i @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2
fireWith @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2
x @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
c @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
n.<computed> @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
getJSON @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
init @ map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:182
(anonymous) @ map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:2029
(anonymous) @ map-template.js?ver=1.0.0:2282
```

Can I fix this by myself?

Thank you so much for any help!
kind regards,
mira

Comment: Please share you code. It's impossible to help you if we can't see it.

Comment: How do I share my code?

Comment: By sharing, I just mean copy & paste it. Do you have the code? Or are you just a contributor/administrator in wordpress who haven't even seen the code?

Comment: I am just a Wordpress admin. But I can find and see the code, just don't understand what I am seeing. So you want me to paste the whole source code? (sorry, you probably think I am stupid...)

Comment: Ok, no problem! It's just that this is a site that targets developers, not wordpress admins, so I was confused. If you could just copy the relevant parts of the source code, such as the content of map-template.js or simply the part(s) where `.toString()` is used, that would be great. I understand it's not easy to know which parts are relevant

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand a problem without some detailed context.
But, what I can see, that you are trying to show some list, where some list items are not defined (`undefined`) or have `undefined` fields. So these `undefined` values cannot be converted into strings (`toString()`).

I could be wrong, but what I can suggest is to check presence of all items to show and their fields.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The problem is occuring on the category pages where all the listings under that category used to be displayed. Now it is only showing the "loading" circle , but never loads the listing posts. Also, the list could be switched to map view and all the listings in that category would be displayed as markers on the map and the map was showing only our region. now it is back to "default", showing the whole world. 
Hope this clarifies the problem.